# sagetex and mcexam

Tags: sagetex, mcexam

I would like to use mcexam and sagetex together. I managed to make things almost work. Well, I have the expected output, but I have too many errors, and don't see where do they come from. [Here](https://cocalc.com/share/b78f5e46924f2440395d4a7aec0de6c348b7c4de/MonExemple.tex?viewer=share) is my minimal working example, I have errors at line 52. When I ommit the last question though, everything is alright.

Also, it seems that putting the `sagesilent` blocks inside the `mcquestions` causes problems, or at least that's what I understood. Any idea?

Compiling with pdf latex, sage 9.0 on ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: The problem has to do with the 3 lines beginning with `\answer $x^\sage{a-1}$`. Exponentiation only applies to \ after the carat. To include multiple characters, put them inside {}. If you write it as `\answer $x^{\sage{a-1}}$` and fix the other lines in similar fashion then your code runs without error.

Comment: Great! 
That is an answer, not a coment!